# Count the Null columns in a row in SQL

Tags: sql

I was wondering about the possibility to count the null columns of row in SQL, I have a table Customer that has nullable values, simply I want a query that return an int of the number of null columns for certain row(certain customer).

Comment: That is not what you should want to do in sql

Comment: For my own curiosity, why would you want to know this?

Comment: What RDBMS? What are the columns? Are they all of the same datatype?

Comment: you mean that any solution for that case would be ugly solution?

Comment: @SpectralGhost The case is the that I want to construct a progress bar for the customer to fill his info, so I need to get the total number of columns and the number of columns which is null so I can get the percentage of the filled data.

Comment: Ah, an interesting and logical reason for wanting to do this. +1

Comment: @zerkms - Why not? You want to know how well you know that SQL row.

Comment: @andowero if you read all the comments and the checked answer you will see that what OP asked and what they _really_ need is 2 different tasks: my comment original meaning is "if you need this - then you probably need to rephrase your problem so that you didn't need it", and it's the case there.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

This method assigns a 1 or 0 for null columns, and adds them all together. Hopefully you don't have too many nullable columns to add up here...

```
SELECT 
  ((CASE WHEN col1 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  + (CASE WHEN col2 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  + (CASE WHEN col3 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  ...
  ...
  + (CASE WHEN col10 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS sum_of_nulls
FROM table
WHERE Customer=some_cust_id
```

Note, you can also do this perhaps a little more syntactically cleanly with `IF()` if your RDBMS supports it.

```
SELECT 
  (IF(col1 IS NULL, 1, 0)
  + IF(col2 IS NULL, 1, 0)
  + IF(col3 IS NULL, 1, 0)
  ...
  ...
  + IF(col10 IS NULL, 1, 0)) AS sum_of_nulls
FROM table
WHERE Customer=some_cust_id
```

I tested this pattern against a table and it appears to work properly.

Comment: `IF()` may well look syntactically cleaner, but `CASE` is more universally supported. Still, to continue this line, from the most universal solution to the cleanest one, I would suggest the following: `SELECT ((col1 IS NULL) + (col2 IS NULL) + ...) AS sum_of_nulls FROM ...`.

Comment: @ImanMarashi I am unsure what you are asking. The result of this query is a single integer column representing the count of NULL columns per row.

Answer (score 5):

My answer builds on [Michael Berkowski's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8596541/1017257), but to avoid having to type out hundreds of column names, what I did was this:

**Step 1:** Get a list of all of the columns in your table

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'myTable';
```

**Step 2:** Paste the list in Notepad++ (any editor that supports regular expression replacement will work). Then use this replacement pattern

- Search:

  ```
  ^(.*)$
  ```
- Replace:

  ```
  \(CASE WHEN \1 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END\) +
  ```

**Step 3:** Prepend `SELECT identityColumnName,` and change the very last `+` to `AS NullCount FROM myTable` and optionally add an `ORDER BY...`

```
SELECT 
    identityColumnName, 
    (CASE WHEN column001 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
    -- ...
    (CASE WHEN column200 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NullCount
FROM
    myTable
ORDER BY 
    NullCount DESC
```

Comment: You could also make use of sys.columns or something similar to concatenate all of those without something like Notepad.

Answer (score 1):

You don't state RDBMS. For SQL Server 2008...

```
SELECT CustomerId,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) - COUNT(C)
        FROM   (VALUES(CAST(Col1 AS SQL_VARIANT)),
                      (Col2),
                      /*....*/
                      (Col9),
                      (Col10)) T(C)) AS NumberOfNulls
FROM   Customer
```

Answer (score 1):

For **ORACLE**-DBMS only.

You can use the [NVL2](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions106.htm) function:

```
NVL2( string1, value_if_not_null, value_if_null )
```

Here is a select with a similiar approach as Michael Berkowski suggested:

```
SELECT (NVL2(col1, 0, 1) 
        + NVL2(col2, 0, 1)
        + NVL2(col3, 0, 1)
        ...
        ...
        + NVL2(col10, 0, 1)
        ) AS sum_of_nulls
FROM table
WHERE Customer=some_cust_id
```

---

A more generic approach would be to write a PL/SQL-block and use dynamic SQL. You have to build a SELECT string with the *NVL2* method from above for every column in the *all_tab_columns* of a specific table.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, in a standard SQL statement you will have to enter each column you want to test, to test all programatically you could use T-SQL.  A word of warning though, ensure you are working with genuine NULLS, you can have blank stored values that the database will not recognise as a true NULL (I know this sounds strange).

You can avoid this by capturing the blank values and the NULLS in a statement like this:

```
CASE WHEN col1 & '' = '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Or in some databases such as Oracle (not sure if there are any others) you would use:

```
CASE WHEN col1 || '' = '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to do, and if you ignore mavens, and if you use SQL Server 2012, you could to it another way. .

The total number of candidate columns ("slots") must be known.
 1. Select all the known "slots" column by column (they're known).
 2. Unpivot that result to get a
    table with one row per original column. This works because the null columns don't
    unpivot, and you know all the column names.
 3. Count(*) the result to get the number of non-nulls;
    subtract from that to get your answer.

Like this, for 4 "seats" in a car

```
select 'empty seats' = 4 - count(*)
from 
(
    select carId, seat1,seat2,seat3,seat4 from cars where carId = @carId
) carSpec
unpivot (FieldValue FOR seat in ([seat1],[seat2],[seat3],[seat4])) AS results
```

This is useful if you may need to do more later than just count the number of non-null columns, as it gives you a way to manipulate the columns as a set too.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the number of columns which are not null. you can apply this appropriately

```
SELECT   ISNULL(COUNT(col1),'') + ISNULL(COUNT(col2),'') +ISNULL(COUNT(col3),'') 
   FROM TABLENAME
   WHERE  ID=1
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, the `ISNULL()` isn't required, as `COUNT(*)` returns a value.  Note that `ISNULL()` isn't present on every system, and the OP never specified what RDBMS he was using, meaning the answer might not have worked for him either.  And finally... if `COUNT()` somehow _did_ return a null, the fact that you're returning a **blank** is going to cause this to fail; either you get a character string instead of the total, or the DB complains about type mismatches.  For that, and the fact the question is nearly 2 years old with an accepted answer, -1 (basic idea works though)

Answer (score 0):

The below script gives you the `NULL` value count within a row i.e. how many columns do not have values.

```
{SELECT
    *,
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM (VALUES (Tab.Col1)
                ,(Tab.Col2)
                ,(Tab.Col3)
                ,(Tab.Col4)) InnerTab(Col) 
        WHERE Col IS NULL) NullColumnCount
FROM (VALUES(1,2,3,4)
            ,(NULL,2,NULL,4)
            ,(1,NULL,NULL,NULL)) Tab(Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4) }
```

Just to demonstrate I am using an inline table in my example.

Try to cast or convert all column values to a common type it will help you to compare the column of different type.

Comment: I am not familiar with "InnerTab". I googled it and can not find a definition. Could someone provide a clue for me as to what this means?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it yet, but I'd try to do it using a PL\SQL function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE ANYARRAY AS TABLE OF ANYDATA
;

CREATE OR REPLACE Function COUNT_NULL
( ARR IN ANYARRAY )
RETURN number
IS
   cnumber number ;
BEGIN

   for i in 1 .. ARR.count loop
     if ARR(i).column_value is null then
       cnumber := cnumber + 1;
     end if;
   end loop;

RETURN cnumber;

EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
   raise_application_error
   (-20001,'An error was encountered - '
   ||SQLCODE||' -ERROR- '||SQLERRM);
END
;
```

Then use it in a select query like this

```
CREATE TABLE TEST (A NUMBER, B NUMBER, C NUMBER);

INSERT INTO TEST (NULL,NULL,NULL);
INSERT INTO TEST (1   ,NULL,NULL);
INSERT INTO TEST (1   ,2   ,NULL);
INSERT INTO TEST (1   ,2   ,3   );

SELECT ROWNUM,COUNT_NULL(A,B,C) AS NULL_COUNT FROM TEST;
```

Expected output

```
ROWNUM | NULL_COUNT
-------+-----------
     1 | 3
     2 | 2
     3 | 1
     4 | 0
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how i tried

```
CREATE TABLE #temptablelocal (id int NOT NULL, column1 varchar(10) NULL, column2 varchar(10) NULL, column3 varchar(10) NULL, column4 varchar(10) NULL, column5 varchar(10) NULL, column6 varchar(10) NULL);


INSERT INTO #temptablelocal
VALUES (1,
        NULL,
        'a',
        NULL,
        'b',
        NULL,
        'c')
SELECT *
FROM #temptablelocal
WHERE id =1
  SELECT count(1) countnull
  FROM
    (SELECT a.ID,
            b.column_title,
            column_val = CASE b.column_title    
            WHEN 'column1' THEN a.column1 
            WHEN 'column2' THEN a.column2 
            WHEN 'column3' THEN a.column3 
            WHEN 'column4' THEN a.column4 
            WHEN 'column5' THEN a.column5 
            WHEN 'column6' THEN a.column6 
            END
     FROM
       ( SELECT id,
                column1,
                column2,
                column3,
                column4,
                column5,
                column6
        FROM #temptablelocal
        WHERE id =1 ) a
     CROSS JOIN
       ( SELECT 'column1'
        UNION ALL SELECT 'column2'
        UNION ALL SELECT 'column3'
        UNION ALL SELECT 'column4'
        UNION ALL SELECT 'column5'
        UNION ALL SELECT 'column6' ) b (column_title) ) AS pop WHERE column_val IS NULL
  DROP TABLE #temptablelocal
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Similary, but dynamically:

```
drop table if exists myschema.table_with_nulls;

create table myschema.table_with_nulls as

select 
   n1::integer,
   n2::integer,
   n3::integer,
   n4::integer,
   c1::character varying,
   c2::character varying,
   c3::character varying,
   c4::character varying
from 
   (
      values 
         (1,2,3,4,'a','b','c','d'),
         (1,2,3,null,'a','b','c',null),
         (1,2,null,null,'a','b',null,null),
         (1,null,null,null,'a',null,null,null)
   ) as test_records(n1, n2, n3, n4, c1, c2, c3, c4);


drop function if exists myschema.count_nulls(varchar,varchar);

create function myschema.count_nulls(schemaname varchar, tablename varchar) returns void as 
$BODY$
   declare
      calc varchar;
      sqlstring varchar;
begin
   select
      array_to_string(array_agg('(' || trim(column_name) || ' is null)::integer'),' + ') 
   into
      calc
   from
      information_schema.columns
   where 
      table_schema in ('myschema') 
         and table_name in ('table_with_nulls'); 

   sqlstring = 'create temp view count_nulls as select *, ' || calc || '::integer as count_nulls from myschema.table_with_nulls';

   execute sqlstring;

   return;
end;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql STRICT;

select * from myschema.count_nulls('myschema'::varchar,'table_with_nulls'::varchar);


select
   *
from 
   count_nulls;
```

Though I see that I didn't finish parametising the function.

Answer (score 0):

My answer builds on [Drew Chapin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50646694/1252947), but with changes to get the result using a single script:

```
use <add_database_here>;
Declare @val Varchar(MAX); 

Select @val = COALESCE(@val + str, str) From 
    (SELECT
    '(CASE WHEN '+COLUMN_NAME+' IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +' str
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = '<add table name here>'
    ) t1 -- getting column names and adding the case when to replace NULLs for zeros or ones
    
Select @val = SUBSTRING(@val,1,LEN(@val) - 1) -- removing trailling add sign
    
Select @val = 'SELECT <add_identity_column_here>, ' + @val + ' AS NullCount FROM <add table name here>' -- adding the 'select' for the column identity, the 'alias' for the null count column, and the 'from'

EXEC (@val) --executing the resulting sql
```

Answer (score 0):

With ORACLE:

```
Number_of_columns - json_value( json_array( comma separated list of columns ), '$.size()' ) from your_table
```

json_array will build an array with only the non null columns and the json_query expression will give you the size of the array

Answer (score -1):

There isn't a straightforward way of doing so like there would be with counting rows.  Basically, you have to enumerate all the columns that might be null in one expression.

So for a table with possibly null columns `a`, `b,` `c`, you could do this:

```
SELECT key_column, COALESCE(a,0) + COALESCE(b,0) + COALESCE(c,0) null_col_count
  FROM my_table
```

Comment: This won't work. If a,b,c aren't numeric it will raise an error. If they are numeric it will return the wrong results.