# Count number of Not Null fields within a Row

Tags: sql, select, null, count

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Count the Null columns in a row in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8596500/count-the-null-columns-in-a-row-in-sql)

I've had a dig around for answers to this, but can't find either a working or suitable answer and I'm a novice with SQL.

I've got a table containing teams for an event, and amongst other columns I have `team_member_1`, `team_member_2`, `team_member_3`, `team_member_4`, `team_member_5`. Each one stores the name of that team memember, each team has a different amount of members (between 3 and 5).

I'm trying count the number of people in a team by counting how many columns/ fields within that row/team are `NOT NULL`.

If my head if would go something like:

```
Select Count NOT NULL team_member_1, team_member_2, team_member_3,  
                      team_member_4, team_member_5 
from Teams 
where team_id = 5
```

Of course this doesn't work. I then want to times this figure by £20 (as the event cost is £20 per head), to give me the amount each team owes, and that will be echo'd out on the website. Hope all makes sense.

Comment: Your `Teams` table is not well normalized - you need to restructure it to have a `teamId`, `memberId` and possibly a `memberPosition` if that's important. This will make queries much easier.

Comment: Please show your table Description\ERD.

Comment: (Yes I know that possible duplicate question asks the opposite but essentially the same...)

Answer (score 4):

If your server product supports the boolean data type and implicitly converts it to integer when in a proper context, like MySQL does, for instance, then you could try the following pattern:

```
SELECT
  (team_member_1 IS NOT NULL) +
  (team_member_2 IS NOT NULL) +
  (team_member_3 IS NOT NULL) +
  (team_member_4 IS NOT NULL) +
  (team_member_5 IS NOT NULL) AS MemberCount
FROM Teams
WHERE team_id = 5
```

Answer (score 2):

You should have a relation table TeamMember -> Team with relation of 1:n \ n:n.

Then in your query join the two tables,Group by the team and count the team members.

```
select t.Id, count(tm.Id)
from teams t, teams_members tm
where t.Id = tm.Team_Id
group by t.Id
```

Answer (score 1):

Imho, that's a really bad design :)

First of all, I would [normalize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) the db. If that is done, your question about the number of team members is a simple `SELECT COUNT(*) ...`

Make a table for the teams, one for the member and a third where you "concat" the team member with a team.

Answer (score 1):

The key to solve your problem is to use specific if function

For Oracle it could be [DECODE](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/decode.php).

```
SELECT 
 DECODE(COL1, null, 0, 1) +
 DECODE(COL2, null, 0, 1) +
 DECODE(COL3, null, 0, 1) +
 DECODE(COL4, null, 0, 1) AS Result
FROM YOUR_TABLE
```

For MySQL it could be [IF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if).

```
SELECT 
 IF(COL1 is null, 0, 1) +
 IF(COL2 is null, 0, 1) +
 IF(COL3 is null, 0, 1) +
 IF(COL4 is null, 0, 1) AS Result
FROM YOUR_TABLE
```

I you are using the SQL Server, you should use [CASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms181765.aspx) statement

```
SELECT
    CASE COL1 WHEN IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END + 
    CASE COL2 WHEN IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END +
    CASE COL3 WHEN IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END 
FROM YOUR_TABLE
```

Comment: You could use case for all 3!

Comment: +1 for the 3rd version that should work in almost all DBMS.

Comment: +1/-1  MySQL doesn't have a four-arg IF() operator.  CASE WHEN NULL is *never* true.  The DECODE example looks right, though. (Oracle will treat NULLs as equal there).

Comment: Yes, the Case should be: `CASE WHEN Col1 IS NULL THEN ...`

Comment: And `IF()` should be something like this: `IF(Col1 IS NULL, 0, 1)`.

Comment: All errors have been fixed, thank for pointing them out.

Comment: Sorry.. I'm using MySQL. Your answer makes sense, but I can't get it working. Here's what I've got (Thanks in advance):
`<?php
$total_people = ("SELECT 
IF(team_member_1 is null, 0, 1) +
 IF(team_member_2 is null, 0, 1) +
 IF(team_member_3 is null, 0, 1) +
 IF(team_member_4 is null, 0, 1) +
 IF(team_member_5 is null, 0, 1) +
 IF(team_member_6 is null, 0, 1) AS Result
FROM Teams where team_id = $id
");

$total_people = (int) $number_of_people;

echo "<h2>There are ". $number_of_people . " people in the team.</h2>";
?>`

Comment: Try to run it on some RDBMS, then use in script. With PHP I can not help you.

Answer (score -1):

As others have pointed out, this is a bad design and you should try to normalize. However, I'd try something like this:

```
Select Count(*) from teams where
 (team_id = 5) and
 (team_member_1 is not null or
  team_member_2 is not null or
  team_member_3 is not null or
  team_member_4 is not null or
  team_member_5 is not null)
```

You should at least normalize to the first normal form by creating a Team table and a Member table and reference Member to Team.

Comment: This would count Not Null columns but would count rows where at least one field is not null.