# Python SQL Error

Tags: mysql

I've currently got an SQL table, with duplicate entries. Some entries have more information than others, and I would like to get the entry with the most information. This is my code, which fails, and I'm not sure is appropriate to suit my needs.

```
"SELECT * FROM People WHERE Name='%s'
 AND (Surname IS NOT NULL OR Surname IS NULL)
 AND (Year_Born IS NOT NULL OR Year_Born IS NULL)
 AND (Height IS NOT NULL OR Height IS NULL)
 AND (Hair_Color IS NOT NULL OR Hair_Color IS NULL)
 AND (Eye_Color IS NOT NULL OR Eye_Color IS NULL" % (name[0].get_child().get_text())
```

`name[0].get_child().get_text()` -> contains the name of the person I would like to look up.

The only message I get, is the following one:
 "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1"

Comment: And how is your code failing, exactly? An exception with traceback, 0 results?

Comment: In the traceback, I do not get much information. The only message is this:
 "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1"

Comment: Update your question with this info.

Comment: Now that it's formatted better, Your query is failing because you're missing a close paren at the end. That being said, checking for something OR not something evaluates to 1 in logic.

Comment: Indeed, you're right, Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query fails because you are missing a close paren at the end:

```
 AND (Eye_Color IS NOT NULL OR Eye_Color IS NULL" %
 AND (Eye_Color IS NOT NULL OR Eye_Color IS NULL)" %
                                                ^
```

As for your actual problem, see these questions:

- [SQL: how to select the row with most known values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10242991/sql-how-to-select-the-row-with-most-known-values)
- [Count number of Not Null fields within a Row [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689407/count-number-of-not-null-fields-within-a-row)
- [Count the Null columns in a row in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8596500/count-the-null-columns-in-a-row-in-sql)