# How to get count of columns that are having null values for a given row in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, multiple-columns, notnull

I have a table that are having 115 columns.
Out of 7 columns I need to get the count of columns that are having not null values for a given row.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count the Null columns in a row in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8596500/count-the-null-columns-in-a-row-in-sql)

Comment: Deepa Das - If one of the answers for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65335253/10819573) resolved your issue, you can help the community by marking that as accepted. An accepted answer helps future visitors use the solution confidently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is to use `case` and `+`:

```
select t.*,
       ( (case when col1 is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
         (case when col2 is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
         (case when col3 is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
         (case when col4 is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
         (case when col5 is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
         (case when col6 is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
         (case when col7 is not null then 1 else 0 end)
        ) as cnt_not_nulls_in_row 
from t;
```

In MySQL, this can be simplified to:

```
select t.*,
       ( (col1 is not null ) +
         (col2 is not null ) +
         (col3 is not null ) +
         (col4 is not null ) +
         (col5 is not null ) +
         (col6 is not null ) +
         (col7 is not null ) 
        ) as cnt_not_nulls_in_row 
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may first query the given `row` from the `table` using the primary key and the use `COUNT` to count the number of columns from the queried row having null value, as follows:

```
WITH derived_row as 
      (SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7 FROM table WHERE primary_key=key)
SELECT COUNT(CASE
                 WHEN col1 IS NULL THEN 1
                 WHEN col2 IS NULL THEN 1
                 WHEN col3 IS NULL THEN 1
                 WHEN col4 IS NULL THEN 1
                 WHEN col5 IS NULL THEN 1
                 WHEN col6 IS NULL THEN 1
                 WHEN col7 IS NULL THEN 1
             END) AS null_column_count
FROM derived_row;
```