# Iterate over dates in java

Tags: java, date, for-loop, iteration

I need to iterate through a range of dates. Not sure on how to take next day in for loop.
I am using `java.util.Date`. So `plusDays(1)` cannot be used in the for loop for taking next date.

Used `date1 = new Date(date1.getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24))` in for loop. But I don't think its a good idea to create objects by calling new each time in for loop.

Please suggest a better way for taking next day in for loop.

Comment: Why are you adding 1 day in a loop?

Comment: You can't have the *next* date without constructing a new Date instance. So that has to be done. And speaking of `plusDays()`, why are you not using `java.time.LocalDate`?

Comment: Why are you using `Date`? That class is poorly designed and long outdated and will not work for what you want. If you do need `Date` for some legacy API, you will need some conversion/s. IMHO the best you can do then is convert to and from `LocalDate` or `ZonedDateTime` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

```java
LocalDate.now().plusDays( 1 )  // Get tomorrow's date.
```

## Avoid legacy date-time classes.

Never use `java.util.Date`.

That terrible class was supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. Ditto for `Calendar`, `GregorianCalendar`, and `SimpleDateFormat`.

## `LocalDate`

For a date-only value, without time-of-day and without time zone, use `LocalDate` class.

Call `LocalDate.now` to get the current date.

For any particular moment, the date varies around the globe by time zone. So, specify the time zone by which you want to view the date. If omitted, you get the JVM’s current default time zone implicitly applied.

```java
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ) ;  // Capture the current date as seen in a particular time zone.
for ( int i = 0 ; i < 7 ; i++ )
{
    LocalDate localDate = today.plusDays( i );
    System.out.println( "localDate = " + localDate );
}
```

When run.

```
localDate = 2020-12-17
localDate = 2020-12-18
localDate = 2020-12-19
localDate = 2020-12-20
localDate = 2020-12-21
localDate = 2020-12-22
localDate = 2020-12-23
```

If you are comfortable with Java streams, use `LocalDate::datesUntil`.

```java
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) );  // Capture the current date as seen in a particular time zone.
today.datesUntil( today.plusWeeks( 1 ) ).forEach( System.out :: println );
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), a process known as [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `plusDays()` by converting your [`Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) into [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.time.*;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Date date = new Date();
        LocalDate dateCopy =  date.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
        System.out.println("Date:  " + dateCopy);
        
        for(int counter = 1; counter <= 5; counter++){
            dateCopy = dateCopy.plusDays(1);
            System.out.println("Date:  " + dateCopy);

        }
    }
}
```

Notice that I use the same `dateCopy` variable, since plusDays() return a copy of `LocalDate` and I don't want to create new variables.

Codes above will produce the following console logs:

```
Date:  2020-12-17
Date:  2020-12-18
Date:  2020-12-19
Date:  2020-12-20
Date:  2020-12-21
Date:  2020-12-22
```

Comment: No need to mix the terrible legacy class `Date` with the *java.time* classes.

Answer (score 2):

All the existing answers are great. This answer provides some additional information which can also solve your problem or at least lead you in the right direction.

### Using the modern API:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.of(2020, 12, 5);// 5th Dec 2020
        LocalDate endDate = LocalDate.of(2020, 12, 15);// 15th Dec 2020
        for (LocalDate date = startDate; !date.isAfter(endDate); date = date.plusDays(1)) {
            System.out.println(date);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-12-05
2020-12-06
2020-12-07
2020-12-08
2020-12-09
2020-12-10
```

**If you have dates as string objects:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d/M/uuuu");
        LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.parse("5/12/2020", dtf);// 5th Dec 2020
        LocalDate endDate = LocalDate.parse("10/12/2020", dtf);// 10th Dec 2020
        for (LocalDate date = startDate; !date.isAfter(endDate); date = date.plusDays(1)) {
            System.out.println(date);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-12-05
2020-12-06
2020-12-07
2020-12-08
2020-12-09
2020-12-10
```

### Using the legacy API:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(2020, 11, 5);// 5th Dec 2020
        Date startDate = calendar.getTime();

        calendar.set(2020, 11, 10);// 10th Dec 2020
        Date endDate = calendar.getTime();

        SimpleDateFormat sdfForOutput = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date date = startDate;
        for (calendar.setTime(startDate); !date.after(endDate); calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR,
                1), date = calendar.getTime()) {
            System.out.println(sdfForOutput.format(date));
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-12-05
2020-12-06
2020-12-07
2020-12-08
2020-12-09
2020-12-10
```

**If you have dates as string objects:**

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat sdfForParsing = new SimpleDateFormat("d/M/yyyy");
        Date startDate = sdfForParsing.parse("5/12/2020");// 5th Dec 2020
        Date endDate = sdfForParsing.parse("10/12/2020");// 10th Dec 2020
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        SimpleDateFormat sdfForOutput = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date date = startDate;
        for (calendar.setTime(startDate); !date.after(endDate); calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR,
                1), date = calendar.getTime()) {
            System.out.println(sdfForOutput.format(date));
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-12-05
2020-12-06
2020-12-07
2020-12-08
2020-12-09
2020-12-10
```

Note that the date-time API of `java.util` and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html). Learn more about the modern date-time API at **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

**Note:** For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7.

If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

Answer (score 0):

As the others said, avoid using `java.util.Date` if there’s any way you can. Prefer the good answer by Basil Bourque.

Sometimes we need to interoperate with legacy code that uses the legacy date-time classes as `Date` and that we cannot afford to upgrade to java.time right away.

- If you get a `Date` form a legacy API, use the answer by ariefbayu.
- If the other way around for each date iterated you need an old-fashioned `Date` object for a legacy API, I will show you how.

  ```
   LocalDate startDateInclusive = LocalDate.of(2021, Month.MARCH, 12);
   LocalDate endDateExlusive = LocalDate.of(2021, Month.MARCH, 17);

   startDateInclusive.datesUntil(endDateExlusive)
           .map(d -> d.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()))
           .map(ZonedDateTime::toInstant)
           .map(Date::from)
           .forEach(System.out::println);
  ```

I ran this snippet in `America/Cambridge_Bay` time zone and got this output:

> ```
> Fri Mar 12 00:00:00 MST 2021
> Sat Mar 13 00:00:00 MST 2021
> Sun Mar 14 00:00:00 MST 2021
> Mon Mar 15 00:00:00 MDT 2021
> Tue Mar 16 00:00:00 MDT 2021
> ```

`LocalDate.datesUnitil()` gives us a stream of `LocalDate`s. Through a series of `map` operations I convert each `LocalDate` to a `Date`, which I finally print. Instead of printing you will want to call one or more legacy methods, for example:

```
            .forEach(jud -> {
                someLegayMethod(jud);
                someOtherLegacyMethod(jud, "some other argument");
            });
```

In the output above you will notice that Java knows that summer time (DST) is introduced on March 14, so from March 15 the time zone abbreviation is `MDT` for Mountain Daylight Time rather than `MST` for Mountain Standard Time. There are really only 23 hours between those two `Date` objects when they both fall at 00:00.

> Used `date1 = new Date(date1.getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24))` in
> for loop. But I don't think its a good idea to create objects by
> calling new each time in for loop.

Creating a new object each time is no problem (except in very special situations). There are a couple of other reasons why your code is not good:

- It’s a bad habit to do our own time math. We should rely on the library classes because

  a. it gives code that is clearer to read

  b. date and time math is most often more complicated than we think and therefore easy to get wrong; specifically we may miss a lot of corner cases, which often goes unnoticed in test.
- Your code assumes that a day is always 24 hours. As I said above, this is not the case.

### Link

[Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.